# ¿Por qué no aparece el output en mi proyecto en Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

Tengo un proyecto que en principio compila pero no se muestra en la consola, he buscado de diferentes maneras a qué se debe pero no encuentro qué puede ser. Ayuda, muchas gracias =)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero lo que has ejecutado y aparece en la consola, no se corresponde con el código que nos muestras. Ponte sobre el archivo que quieres ejecutar, Principal.java, pulsa el botón derecho del ratón y selecciona la opción de ejecutar.

Answer (score 0):

Para estar seguro de que se ejecuta el archivo correcto, haz clic derecho en el desde el explorador y selecciona la opción Run o Ejecutar, en otro caso me ha ocurrido que NetBeans no ejecuta mis programas y debo cerrarlo y abrirlo

Comment: Al ejecutar como me indicas, desde el explorar, me aparece: "Class "com.prog03.Principal.Principal" does no have main method.

Comment: muchísimas gracias por la ayuda